# How to show and change incoming data dropdown when doing react getId

Tags: reactjs, rest, get, dropdown, primereact

How can I write this structure in order to show the selected data in the memberTitle list in the dropdown list in the getId operation with rest and provide the change.

```
 <Dropdown placeholder="Member Title"
  className={isError.memberTitle != null ? "is-invalid form-control" : "form-control"}
  name="memberTitle"
  value={memberTitle}
  options={this.state.memberList}
  optionLabel="label"
  optionValue="value"
  onChange={(e) => {this.setState({memberTitle: e.value})}}/>
```

memberList is holding memberTitles

Comment: Can you share a sample of the JSON of your memberList?

Comment: And try to set the value of the target of event like this:

onChange={(e) => {this.setState({memberTitle: e.target.value})}}/>